# Is it possible to configure hibernate to not insist if password is not correct?

Tags: java, hibernate

Is is possible to configure hibernate to not insist on trying to connect if it detects that the password is wrong (to try to avoid locking the account)? Say, would rather have a service to fail when starting the application.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22880345/2970947) you go.

Comment: That's ok but it's not a pure-hibernate solution, say. Would like to be able to configure something on hibernate per-se.